# Is there a way to align MUI GRID elements to flex-start?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to center my main MUI grid using the justify property which centers the grid but also centers the items in it. I want my grid elements to be aligned `flex-start` instead of being centred with the grid. However, the `align-item` property is not working on the MUI grid.

What am I doing wrong?

App.js

```
   <Container maxWidth="xl" style={{ marginTop: '50px' }}>
      <Grid container spacing={isMobile ? 1 : 8} className="grid-container" justifyContent="center">
        {[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((value) => (
          <Grid key={value} item xs={6} sm={5} md={4} xl={2.6} lg={4}>
            <Box display="flex" justifyContent="center">
              <div style={{ alignSelf: 'flex-start', width: '100%' }}>
                <NavLink to={`/shoepage/${value}`} style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
                  <Igrid />
                </NavLink>
              </div>
            </Box>
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </Container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Grid component in MUI does not render `display: grid` but it renders flex. The `spacing` prop of Grid breaks the styling as it adds a negative margin. Read it [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/#limitations). So, the problem is with the padding that it added when you are using the spacing prop. Here is a basic example without spacing:

```js
const { Box, Grid } = MaterialUI;

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Grid
        container
        style={{
          border: "1px solid red",
          justifyContent: "center",
        }}
      >
        {[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((value) => (
          <Grid
            key={value}
            item
            xs={6}
            sm={5}
            md={4}
            lg={4}
            style={{
              border: "1px solid blue",
              // justifyContent: "flex-start",
            }}
          >
            <Box>
              <div style={{ alignSelf: "flex-start", width: "100%" }}>
                {value}
              </div>
            </Box>
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@mui/material@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```